# Why don't my form get posted correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, html-helper

I am working on MVC POST/GET requests, but I observed some strange behavior.

My form is posted after editing it by clicking "Save" from browser, but when I received the request, all the attributes were undefined. `CourseName`, `CourseCreditPts`, `Institute` were null or zeros.

Code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(tblCourse a_Course)
{
    // Retrieve existing object
    var CourseToBeSaved = _pr.FindCourseById(a_Course.CourseID);

    // without try-catch exception thrown
    try
    {
        TryUpdateModel(CourseToBeSaved);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
    }

    // Save
    _pr.Save();

    return View();
}
```

and the `.aspx` file containing code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<DataWarehouse.tblCourse>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="DataWarehouse.Helpers" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Edit
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <h2>Edit Course</h2>   

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.CourseID) %>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Institute</b></td>

                <td><%: Html.DropDownList("InstituteID")%> <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.InstituteID) %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>CourseName</b></td>
                <td><%: Html.TextBox("EditAbleCourseName")%> <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CourseName)%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>CreditPoints</b></td>
                <td><%: Html.TextBox("EditAbleCreditPoints")%> <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CreditPts)%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Status</b></td>
                <td><%: Html.DropDownList("EditAbleStatus")%> <%:    Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Status)%></td>
            </tr>

        </table>            
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>

    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t post how the tblCourse class is defined, but from your validators it seems like it has a property called CourseName. You have named the textbox that should contain the course name EditAbleCourseName and there is your problem. For default model binding you have to name the inputs to the same name as the property on the class. This goes for your other properties too.

So try to rename your inputs to the same name as the properties on your class.

```
<%: Html.TextBox("CourseName")%>
```

and so on...

Comment: This problem is solved. But during this another problem arised. CourseID (Primary Key value is not transferred properly from browser's POST request) and CourseID is 0. instead it should be like in current editing course case ( must be 136). As I have to update Model Redirect the page by using this ID.